# sed での変数指定方法

Tags: sed

⓵ `sed -e '$row_number,$d' $job_name`

任意のファイル（`$job_name`）に対して、任意の行数（`$row_number`）から最終行を
削除したいと考えています。

変数として、下記を割り当てています。

`$row_number`
`$job_name`

⓵の実行結果が望んだ様になりません。

調べた結果、どうも、`'$row_number,$d'`の部分に問題があるかと考えていますが、
正解がわかりません。※変数の指定方法に問題があるのではないかと考えています。

あるサイトでは、「'」は不要と書かれていました。しかし、実行結果は、指定行は削除されませんでした。

教示頂きたいです。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考までに: `set -x` をシェルで実行しておくと、シェルが実際に実行したコマンドを出力できます。元に戻すには `set +x` を実行します。

Comment: masmさん 回答いただき有難うございます。パソコンの調子が悪く、本日復旧しました。
アドバイスい頂いた内容を試させていただきます。 ※初心者の為、一から自分がやろうとしていたことを、再度整理（思い出して）みます。

Answer (score 3):

`'` の位置を変えてみましょう。

```
sed -e $row_number',$d' $job_name
```

`$row_number` は shell によって解釈されるようになりますし、
また、`$d` は `'` で囲まれているので shell によって解釈されません。

あと、上に挙げた方法だと、標準出力に結果が出力されます。もし `$job_name` に指定したファイルを書き換えたい、ということでしたら、`-i` を付けるとできます。

```
sed -i -e $row_number',$d' $job_name
```

書き換えちゃうと元には戻りませんので、慎重にどうぞ。

Comment: 回答は問題ないですが、mac やbsdのsedは-iの挙動がlinuxと微妙に違い、オプションで拡張子を渡す必要があり、その拡張子でバックアップが作られます

Answer (score 0):

こういう感じでしょうか？
`-i`オプションの方がお好みでしたら書き換えてください。

```
# sedでやるなら
sed -e "$row_number~1d" <"$job_name"

# headでもいいような
head -n "${row_number:+$((row_number-1))}" "$job_name"
# 単純化するなら
head -n "$((row_number-1))" "$job_name"
```